Run jobs based on whether or not variable is set
In my GitLab CI pipeline, I have certain jobs which I want to run only when I create a tag (so, when $CI_COMMIT_TAG is set) and other jobs which I want to not run in such a situation.  I tried
when_tag:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: always
  script:
    - echo "Tag"

when_no_tag:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
  script:
    - echo "No tag"

However, when I made this commit to my repo (so, $CI_COMMIT_TAG should be unset), neither of the two jobs ran.

Because the when_no_tag job specifies rules, GitLab will go down the list of rules and find the first one that matches.  Because a regular commit doesn't have the CI_COMMIT_TAG variable set, the first and only rule will not match.
Since no rules match, the job is not added to the pipeline.  You can think of an implicit - when: never added to the end of the rules.  So, if you want the job to run only when there's no tag, you should instead do
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    when: never
  - when: on_success

You could also do - when: always but that would run the job even if previous stages failed.
